# Python Referencing data by interpolation

Tags: python, datetime, interpolation

I have two datasets, One of which has time array in datetime.datetime form, and x,y,z coordinates array of that time, like `time[0]=datetime.datetime(2000,1,21,0,7,25), x[0]=-6.7, etc.`

I'd like to calculate something from the coordinates, but that needs another parameter (Ma) which depend on time. Second data set has another time array in same datetime form, and the parameter recorded at that time, like `time[0]=datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,3), Ma[0]=2.73`

The problem is that the time array of two data set is different (though the ranges are similar)

So I want to interpolate the parameter's value at each time of data set 1, like `Ma[0]`, but 0 is not index of time of dataset2, but corresponds to index of dataset 1.
How can I do that?

PS. Can I convert the time form to simpler one? datetime.datetime seems quite cumbersome.

Comment: Please post a sample of your data. Is it about numpy arrays? Or pandas dataframes?

Comment: @SpghttCd It's currently numpy arrays. I cannot access my data now. I'll do it when I can. Basically np.shape(time)=(2600000, ) and np.shape(time2)=(7000000, ) , x, y, z, Ma are similar array.  (time2 means time array from dataset 2. 'Datasets' here are not python objects, just txt files. I read off arrays from two separate txt files.

Comment: You say the times are different; what is your criteria for matching two times?

Comment: Ok, if it's a datset from textfiles anyway I#d recommend using `pandas`, because for time based data it has a ´resample` function, which could help you here.

Comment: @SimonBrahan So lets say that dataset 2 has parameter information at time 10am and 11am. And I wanna find parameter value corresponding to dataset 1 event, lets say 10:40, then I wanna linearly interpolate the parameter value. (I should have said this in the question. sorry)

Comment: OK. So, you get a timestamp from data set 1, and use linear interpolation between the nearest timestamps in data set 2 to get a value for `Ma`. Is that right?

Comment: @SimonBrahan Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example of how to interpolate your values. The `coord_` and `ma_` arrays will be your imported data.

The first thing the script does is build some more sensible data structures from your disparate 1 dimensional arrays. The part that you're actually looking for is the call to `np.interp`, [documented here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time

# Numpy cannot interpolate between datetimes
# This function converts a datetime to a timestamp
def to_ts(dt):
    return time.mktime(dt.timetuple())

coord_dts = np.array([
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 4, 12)
])

coord_xs = np.array([3, 5, 8, 13])
coord_ys = np.array([2, 3, 5, 7])
coord_zs = np.array([1, 3, 6, 10])

ma_dts = np.array([
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 3),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 4)
])

ma_vals = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Handling the data as separate arrays will be painful.
# This builds an array of dictionaries with the form:
#   [ { 'time': timestamp, 'x': x coordinate, 'y': y coordinate, 'z': z coordinate }, ... ]
coords = np.array([
    { 'time': to_ts(coord_dts[idx]), 'x': coord_xs[idx], 'y': coord_ys[idx], 'z': coord_zs[idx] }
    for idx, _ in enumerate(coord_dts)
])

# Build array of timestamps from ma datetimes
ma_ts = [ to_ts(dt) for dt in ma_dts ]

for coord in coords:
    print("ma interpolated value", np.interp(coord['time'], ma_ts, ma_vals))
    print("at coordinates:", coord['x'], coord['y'], coord['z'])
```